# Unknown type name "list" on C program

Tags: c

i had problem to split program on more files .c and .h 
on main.c i put a struct like

```
struct listnumbers {
  float number;
  struct listnumbers *next;
};typedef struct listnumbers *list;
```

the problem come when i need to compile all files .c .h and compilator  give me an error like  Unknown type name "list" on sorting.h = void sorting(list *pt,float number)

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see the actual errors, in full and unedited. And we need to see the source that caused the errors in the first place.

Comment: On an unrelated note, are you sure you want to define `list` as a *pointer*? For example you show the `sorting` function, which takes a pointer to `list` as its first argument. That means it's a `struct listnumbers **`, a pointer to a pointer. Is that intended? Defining a type as a pointer (like you do) will sooner or later lead to confusion, if not with you then with the people reading your code.

Comment: `struct listnumbers {
  float number;
  struct listnumbers *next;
}; typedef struct listnumbers *list;

void sorting(list *pt, float number);

int main()
{
}` compiles fine here. Your problem is that `list` is unknown in `sorting.h`. You probably need a `list.h` which must be included in `sort.h`.

Comment: If the problem arises when you compile all files `.c` and `.h`, why don't you post some of those files, instead of just attending at the `struct` definition?  Have you included that definition in all places you are using it?  Be sure if the compiler is complainting about type `list` not found, is because that type is not defined anywhere.  Think on what can happen for that type not to be recognised by the compiler.  Perhaps some typo elsewhere?  The `struct` definition is correct and also is the `typedef`, as you write it there.

Answer (score 4):

C is case sensitive. `Struct` should be `struct`.

The way to go with structs in C is

1. Don't bother with typedefs for structs, they are useless and only save you typing the struct keyword
2. Declare the struct in a public header file and `#include` it only in files needing the `struct`. In other words, write a proper *interface*  and place the interface declaration in the header, the interface implementation in a C file.

Comment: ... they are useless and only save you typing the _struct_ keyword: So they are not useless Id say.

Comment: @TomasF. Saving a few characters to type is useless, considering the loss of maintainability. When I see `struct mumble x` I immediately recognize that I must use `.` and can't ever find a printf format for x, while with `mumble x` I'm blind. What do people do? Spend extra characters for a suffix in `typedef struct mumble mumble_s`. That's, err, crazy. Peter van der Linden goes into more detail in his book *Expert C Programming -- Deep C Secrets*.

Comment: Jens (I.) Maybe you could explain what you mean by _loss of maintainability_. I cant see a point why an alias that completely replaces original keyword and which is defined a line below can harm anything. (II.) When I see a non reserved type identifier such as `mumble` in plain C, I know, its a struct or something no matter struct keyword. (III.) Why to do it that way? I could use `typedef struct uglyNam_e niceName` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your structs in .h files that you include where the struct is used.

*Unknown type name "list" on sorting.h* tries to tell you that while processing `sorting.h` the `list` is unknown.

You can also shorten ist definition by combining typedef + struct.

```
typedef struct listnumbers {
  float number;
  struct listnumbers *next;
} *list;
```

Comment: typedef  struct too?

Comment: i need to remove struct on main.c and put it only on .h files right ?,then i will include .h files on main.c

Comment: Yes, this way compiler is not aware of `list` as I stated.
In simple words you define "what" in .h and "how" in .c files. Defining your structs is a part of "what"

Comment: @zehunixed `typedef struct a { ... } b;` is two things.  A `typedef` statemente defining `b` as the type name of a new type.  And a `struct` definition for type `struct a`.  You can do both because C requires a type definition as argument to a `typedef` statement, and not just a type name.  Either way, your problem is not in the statements you have shown. Edit the question and show how you have arranged the individual `.c` and `.h` files to get the definition included in all compilation units.